# How to call clear cache on Android Native ARM64?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm64, clear-cache

Simple question for simple answer.

I just can't figure out how to clear the instruction cache properly on such architecture.

Did anyone use it?

Comment: Have you looked at what the _ARM®  Architecture Reference Manual
ARMv8, for ARMv8-A architecture profile_ says on the matter?

Comment: I found the answer by myself on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC provide this built-in function

```
__builtin___clear_cache (void* start, void* end)
```

that is automatically managed according to the architecture.

Parameters set the range of memory to cache, where start is inclusive and end is exclusive. Every time a new memory area with instructions to execute, the cache should be cleared for that area.

[reading](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)